# what is difference between these two statements?1.super class method calling first line 2.super class method is calling last line

Tags: android

what is difference between these two statements?

1.super class method calling first line
2.super class method is calling last line

Exmaple：

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, AppConstants.FLURRY_API_KEY);
    RocqAnalytics.startScreen(this);
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this); 

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, AppConstants.FLURRY_API_KEY);
    RocqAnalytics.startScreen(this);
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this); 
    super.onStart();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. By putting the `super.onStart()` at the top of the overridden function, you tell the program to execute any `onStart()` code from the super class **before** any of your code runs.
2. By putting the `super.onStart()` at the end of the overridden function, you tell the program to execute any `onStart()` code from the super class **after** any of your code runs.

This is somewhat important because even a raw `Activity` does some of [its own initialization](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L1157) in `onStart()`. For example, the application lifecycle callbacks are invoked in `Activity.onStart()`. So if you want to do something before the application gets notified that your activity has started, you must do so before calling `super.onStart()`.

In which order of operations you call `super.onStart()` is thus dependent on the fact if you want to do some of your own initialization before or after the framework has a say. As a rule of thumb, I would always initialize the framework first (i.e. call `super.onStart()` first) unless there is an explicit reason not to do so.

Note that this is the other way round for `onPause()`, because the framework's `onPause()` might free resources that you still need for your own cleanup.

So as a general rule: *Initialize framework first, cleanup framework last.* Of course, there are various reasons this rule needs to be broken now or then.